# Eigenvalues of a sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the proof of the "Friendship theorem" in the book "Proofs from the Book" it states that if

$$A^2=(k-1)I+J$$

such that $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the all ones matrix (both $n\times n)$, then:

1. The eigenvalues of $(k-1)I$ are $k-1$ with multiplicity $n$.
2. The eigenvalues of $J$ are $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $n$ with multiplicity 1.
3. $A^2$ eigenvalues are $k-1$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $n+k-1$ with multiplicity 1.

I didn't understand part 3.

By the way - $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a $k$-regular graph that for every two vertices $u,v$ there is a distinct vertex $w$ such that $\{u,w\},\{v,w\}\in E$.

Thanks

Comment: I will assume you mean algebraic, and not geometric, multiplicity (although they work out to be the same in this instance). If you believe statement 2, then you must also believe statement 3. When you add a multiple of $I$ to a matrix $M$, all you are doing to the characteristic polynomial is shifting it. That is, if $f(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - M)$ and $g(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - (M + aI))$, then $g(\lambda) = f(\lambda - a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1. you have multiplicity $n$.

The all ones vector $x = (1,\dotsc,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of $J$ to eigenvalue $n$, and the vectors $y_2 = (1,-1,0,\dotsc,0)^T$, $y_3 = (0,1,-1,0,\dotsc,0)^T$, …, $y_n = (0,\dotsc,0,1,-1)^T$ are eigenvectors of $J$ to the eigenvalue $0$. Notice that $(x,y_1,\dotsc,y_n)$ is a basis of $K^n$.

Now
$$
 A^2 x = (k-1)Ix + Jx = (k-1)x + nx = (n+k-1)x,
$$
so $x$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ to the eigenvalue $n+k-1$. For all $2 \leq i \leq n$ we have
$$
 A^2 y_i = (k-1) I y_i + J y_i = (k-1)y_i,
$$
so $y_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ to the eigenvalue $k-1$. So $(x, y_1, \dotsc, y_n)$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $A^2$, and we directly get 3. by counting.

Comment: Thanks! 
(BTW, What's $K^n$? Just the $n$'th dimensional vector space?)

Comment: Yes; it’s just the space of column vectors with $n$ entries. So in the case of  $K = \mathbb{R}$ (for example) it’s just good old $\mathbb{R}^n$.